# Line-height lower than Font-size

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to apply the "line-height" property on "display:inline" elements when this "line-height" propriety is smaller than the element "font-size" property.

Here a little exemple : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVywyz

In this exemple you can see what i have at the moment, the result i would like to have and what i've already tested.

---

The html code is generated via php, the container containing my spans element dont have a fixed width, also, spans can be generated in many ways :

```
<p>
  <span>Some text</span><br>
  <span>Some text</span>
</p>
```

or

```
<p>
  <span>Some text</span><span>Some texte 2</span>
</p>
```

---

- Possibility 1 : Add "display:inline-block" on each span elements

=> As you can see in the case 3 of my "codepen.io" exemple, it can't works as it will change the global display

- Possibility 2 : Add the "line-height" on the span container

=> Every container can have many spans, and i don't want to apply a specific line-height to all these spans, you can see in the case 4 what it will give.

---

Also, the html generated is used in an wysiwyg editor, so i'm looking for a solution where i dont have to use "div" or "floating elements" (if possible, but to be honest any solutions would be welcomed)

If you got any idea feel free to answer,

Regards,

Comment: How about determining which of the spans in the p need to have the smaller line-height and then putting those spans in a wrapper inside the p. So `<p><span class="wrapper">(your spans...)</span>(unaffected spans...)</p>` and giving `.wrapper` the line-height and display inline-block.

Comment: Thanks for answering, i've updated the codepen with your solution but unfortunately this will not work in some case, like when you've 2 spans with different line-height in the same line. In fact, it will have the same effect that if we were putting the display:inline-block to our span with the line-height lower than font-size